# How does LambdaExpression resolve to Expression<Func<T, returnT>> at runtime via dynamic?

Tags: c#, linq, generics, dynamic, lambda

I have some working code where `Expression<Func<T, returnT>>` objects of differing types are placed in a `List<LambdaExpression>`, and then at runtime are matched up with methods that accept `Expression<Func<T, returnT>>` by using `dynamic`.  This was my first use of `dynamic` but I feel I understand its role/function well enough.  What I'm curious about is the relationship/resolution from `LambdaExpression` to `Expression<Func<T, returnT>>`.  The code is below:

```
public void DoIt(Expression<Func<Record, string>> expr) { ... }
public void DoIt(Expression<Func<Record, int?>> expr) { ... }        
public void DoIt(Expression<Func<Record, DateTime?>> expr) { ... }


public class Record {
    public string Member1;
    public int? Member2;
    public DateTime? Member3;
}

Expression<Func<Record, string>> expr1 = r => r.Member1;
Expression<Func<Record, int?>> expr2 = r => r.Member2;
Expression<Func<Record, DateTime?>> expr3 = r => r.Member3;

var myList = new List<LambdaExpression>() {
    expr1, expr2, expr3
};

//later...

foreach (var expr in myList)
{
    DoIt((dynamic) expr);
    //What is happening w/ this LambdaExpression obj
    //so that it dispatches the appropriate DoIt method?
}
```

Comment: Search for *Dynamic Dispatch*. For instance here [Dynamic Language Runtime Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Thx.  I knew it was dynamic dispatch, but I guess I thought the behavior of dynamic in this instance was somehow exclusive to `LambdaExpression`.  After reading a bit more on it, now I see it's not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Expression<TDelegate>` derives from `LambdaExpression`.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.expressions.lambdaexpression(v=vs.110).aspx):

> At runtime, an expression tree node that represents a lambda
>   expression is always of type Expression < TDelegate >.

Answer (score 1):

Besides the fact that `Expression<TDelegate>` derives from `LambdaExpression` - you are converting the `LambdaExpression` to dynamic - which uses the DLR to determine the object's type.

now your object isn't a `LambdaExpression` but whatever type it will be during runtime. since you are calling a method overload, it knows which overload to call.

when you are using static typing (`var`/`LambdaExpression`) the overload is determined in runtime. In your case there is no `LambdaExpression` overload so it won't compile without converting to dynamic.

when using dynamic typing the overload is determined on runtime using the DLR